# Source of the phrase "call [somebody] out of name"

Tags: etymology, idioms, slang, phrase-origin, origin-unknown

I was introduced today to the phrase "Call out of name" as in:

> She claimed the other girl **called her out of name**.

I had to ask what it meant and the answer was "she called her a bitch". I'm curious about how widely this expression is known and used.  Doing a search on that phrase found an entry in Urban Dictionary and then the title of a book. So, did this phrase come from that book's title and if not, when and where?

Comment: Never heard of it. Are you sure it was from a native speaker? Can you give us a link to the full context?

Comment: @Rathony :  No, it is not that.  It was clearly meant to be " Called her out of her name".

Comment: @FumbleFingers :  Native speaker.  maybe an african-american speaker.   I can't give a link as it was over the phone that I heard it and asked about it.

Comment: @Rathony  unambiguously and unequivocally in that I stopped the speaker and said, " I don't know what 'call her out of her name' means"  and it was explained to me.

Comment: Google Books initially claims about 7,290 results for [called out of his name](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22called+out+of+his+name%E2%80%9D), but when I try to look at them, it turns out there are only 10. And I can only read those words *in context* in one case (which looks to me to have been written by a non-native speaker anyway).

Comment: I found another link to that Maya Angelou short story and she uses it in exactly the same way:  http://www.scribd.com/doc/56802884/What-s-Your-Name-Girl-Angelou    Every person I knew had a hellish horror of being “called out of his name.” It was a dangerous practice to call a Negro anything that could be loosely construed asinsulting because of the centuries of their having been called n_____s….

Comment: Though I can't tell you where the term originated, as an African American I can tell you the term is pretty common knowledge among us.

Comment: Not a normal US idiom, but certainly could be a "slang" term in any of several subcultures.

Comment: Seems to be equivalent to "name calling" though without the irony.  Since name calling never involves the use of your name.  "Call out of name" is actually more straightforward.

Comment: I'm sorry to see so many votes to close this question, which involves a phrase that has a fascinating and seemingly unique history of use. I hope that no one adds the fifth and presumably crucial close vote to the four that have already been cast.

Comment: I feel like people are downvoting because they just haven't heard of this before, even though it is common enough in at least one variety of English. It wan't a mishearing, it was just new to the outsider.

Comment: @Rina Can you comment more on what the meaning is? Is it a euphemism (covering up using harsher language, or is it just the AAVE way of saying  'calling [somebody] names' (or both)?

Comment: @Mitch: Unfortunately, Rina can't comment yet on posts other than her own answers. A moderator very kindly converted her previous comment from an answer into a comment so that her observation wouldn't just disappear when reviewers concluded that it wasn't a formal answer. I would be interested to hear her answer to your followup question.

Comment: I was also looking for a meaning as I had found it in court cases involving seamen in the 1860's ("Cross-examined by defendant: I did not call you out of your name several times. I never called any man in the ship out of his name. " - http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/8822324/775209 - Thank you all for this information.

Comment: Hmm? I'm surprised that people have not heard this before. I wasn't aware that this was slang or non-standard. Not only is it something that I grew up hearing, but I recall reading it in some older literature. At the most it sounds old fashioned, but totally normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Recent use of the phrase in African American English***

The expression has been in use among African Americans for at least 28 years. Geneva Smitherman, *Black Talk: Words and Phrases from the Hood to the Amen Corner* (1994) offers this definition of the term:

> CALL SOMEBODY OUTA THEY NAME To insult someone; to talk about a person in a negative way, especially to call the person a name or to hurl an accusation at the person. "She come talkin bout I stole her ring. I don't appreciate nobody callin me outa my name" (i.e., implying that she's a thief).

A Google Books search finds a number of matches for "called me outa [or *outta*] my name." From Derek Bell, [*And We Are Not Saved: The Elusive Quest For Racial Justice*](https://books.google.com/books?id=c88WBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&dq=%22outta+my+name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmoZLA1efJAhVJ_mMKHeZABLMQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22outta%20my%20name%22&f=false) (1987):

> "All that progress, as you call it, didn't keep that white redneck cop from **calling me outta my name** and pointin' his gun at you when you try to help."
>
> "Well, Delia, that could have happened to anyone interfering like I did."

From [*Living Blues*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GY4JAQAAMAAJ&q=%22outta+my+name%22&dq=%22outta+my+name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij7cKb4-fJAhVN_WMKHSTED4sQ6AEIPzAE), issues 76–83 (1988) [snippet]:

> *Women talks about me and lies on me, **calls me outta my name**.*
>
> *They talks about me, lie about me, **calls me outta my name**.*
>
> *All their men come to see me just the same.*

From Gayl Jones, [*The Healing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5FqSuAhrN6MC&pg=PT107&dq=%22outa+my+name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOzpCd1OfJAhWIsh4KHftCBk0Q6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=%22outa%20my%20name%22&f=false) (1998):

> So some guy noticed your complexion ain't flawless, so what? Guys always telling me about my flaws. I remember the first man that **called me outa my name** called me Possum, on account of I usedta didn't say nothing to nobody about nothing, and especially men.

The phrase appears in various other Google Books texts, as recently as Jazz Jordan, [*Lust & Hip Hop 3*](https://books.google.com/books?id=f3mSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&dq=%22out+of+my+name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn8IzjqenJAhWDLmMKHUroAfYQ6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=%22out%20of%20my%20name%22&f=false) (The Ms. Mogul Series) (2015):

> "You're one crazy bitch. You know that? I gave you everything and then some, and you're gonna play me like this?"
>
> Shontay cut her eyes at him. “I can't believe you had the nerve to **call me out of my name**. I am the mother of your child! Don't you have any respect for me at all? This is one of the reasons why I can't be with you anymore. Besides, I've met somebody else, and I'm in love with another man."

---

***Eighteenth-century use of the phrase in England***

I was very surprised to find instances of "call me out of my name" from the 1700s, though these may or may not be direct ancestors of the term now used in African American slang. From Henry Fielding, [*Joseph Andrews*](https://books.google.com/books?id=W0VSAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22out+of+my+name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcoczC1-fJAhVD22MKHatsBqsQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22out%20of%20my%20name%22&f=false) (1742):

> '...Was ever such a pitiful dog, to take up with such a mean trollop? If she had been a gentlewoman, like myself, it had been some excuse ; but a beggarly, saucy, dirty, servant-maid! Get out of my house, you wh——e!' to which she [Mrs. Tow-wouse] added another name, which we do not care to stain our paper with : it was a monosyllable beginning with b——, and indeed was the same, as if she had pronounced the words, she-dog ; which term we shall, to avoid offence, use on this occasion, though indeed both the mistress and maid uttered the above-mentioned b——, a word extremely disgustful to females of the lower sort. Betty [the servant] had borne all hitherto with patience, and had uttered only lamentations ; but the last appellation stung her to the quick. 'I am a woman as well as yourself,' she roared out, 'and no she-dog; and if I have been a little naughty, I am not the first; if I have been no better than I should be,' cries she, sobbing, 'that's no reason you should **call me out of my name** : my be-betters are wo-orse than me.'

From [*The Batchelor: Or Speculations of Jeoffrey Wagstaffe, Esq.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YG0PAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA145&dq=%22out+of+my+name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGmq2z3ufJAhUM7WMKHf4yCeo4ChDoAQhRMAc#v=onepage&q=%22out%20of%20my%20name%22&f=false) (1769):

> I was beginning to grow serious upon this subject, when I received the following letter. My much valued correspondent, however, **calls me out of my name**, by styling my Speculations the HUMOURIST, as I have have for some time dropped that title, on the very just reasons, and do, for the future, intend to appear under that of my real character, the BATCHELOR, which I have this day assumed.
>
> ...
>
> "Brother Jeoffrey," says she [Letty Love-youth] , "you know I have always kept up a good character with the world, and , thank God, my reputation has always been spotless ; besides, I hope I have behaved towards you as towards you as a tender, affectionate sister ; ('tis true I am many years younger than you) and that I should live to be taunted by that young Gipsy to be **called out of my name** ; in short, to be abused by the scandalous title of Old Maid, is what I cannot bear."

From [*Dr. Last in His Chariot*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NywUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA183&dq=%22out+of+my+name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcoczC1-fJAhVD22MKHatsBqsQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22out%20of%20my%20name%22&f=false) [a translation of Moliere's *Maladie Imaginaire*] (1792):

> *Dr. Last.* My own chariot's below.
>
> *Ailwou'd.* A cart, a wheelbarrow, for such scoundrels.
>
> *Dr. Last.* Don't **call me out of my name**.
>
> *Ailwou'd.* I can't sirrah.
>
> *Dr. Last.* You did, you did, and I'll make you pay for it.
>
> *Ailwou'd.* Get out of my house.

---

***Conclusion***

The instances from the 1700s are astonishingly similar to and consistent with the examples that occur in the 1980s and later, though I can't say with any certainty that the later instances represent a direct survival or revival of the older phrase. But if the modern phrase isn't a survival or revival of the older one, it is certainly the product of a striking coincidence in wording and usage.

Comment: As a child, I was told not to call people outside of their name by my grandparents. The tone was always 'proper', as if they were highfalutin. Thats why im surprised this is considered slang or jargon.